# Quadratic Curve example of fabricjs, but in ts

Tags: typescript, fabricjs

I am trying to recreate the quadratic Curve example (http://fabricjs.com/quadratic-curve). I am working with ts and i have an error on the code below

`var line = new fabric.Path('M 65 0 Q 100 100 200 0', { fill: '', stroke: 'black', objectCaching: false }); line.path[0][1] = 100;`

In js this code works fine but in ts i have this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '1' can't be used to index type 'Point'.
> Property '1' does not exist on type 'Point'.ts(7053)

Does anyone knows how to solve it?
Thank You!

I already tried working with fabric.Points but it didn't really helped at all!

Comment: I think you can just use the "y" property: https://tsplay.dev/mLrOVw